# Resize parent custom View after hiding subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, layout, autolayout

Programming on android is very simple to do it. But in ios, it does not enter my head that I have to recalculate view size every time I have to display or disappear a view.

I've been doing this way

```
 [_viewParent addSubview:exerciseSubViewController.view];

    postionY += exerciseSubViewController.view.frame.size.height;

[ViewHelper setFrameToView:_viewParent
                      posY:_viewParent.frame.origin.y
                      posX:_viewParent.frame.origin.x
                     width:_viewParent.frame.size.width
                    height:postionY];
```

or this way

```
CGSize size = self.viewSubView.frame.size;
[self.viewParent setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width,size.height)];
```

I would like to know if it has something easier, which supports iOS 8.0 +

follows an example below.

image view
[image],

image with out subview
[image: image with out subview]

Comment: *I have to recalculate view size every time I have to display or disappear a view.* - what makes you think that?

Comment: that's how they taught me =(

Comment: How about you show some code first? It's not completely clear what is the problem.

Comment: I edited post with code.

Comment: `UIStackView` is what you're looking for, however it's available since iOS 9.0

Comment: This is easily done with auto-layout and constraints. Have you looked at that yet?

Comment: I've tried UIStackView, but the subView that is visible is getting in the size of the parentView, not the parentView of the subView's size.

Comment: @MateusLima - I'd suggest you take a read through some "introduction to auto-layout" articles. You can do what you're asking fairly easily, once you are familiar with auto-layout - and you can do it with or without Stack Views.